# Use <= to search a range

Tags: formula, openoffice-calc

I want to perform another calculation after checking the range `$N$16:$N$9000` for all dates that are `>=$C$6` as shown below.

```
=IF($N$16:$N$9000>=$C$6; "Y"; "N")
```

I really need a calculation that will test for `>=$C$6` and `<=$C$8`.

The additional equation has been tested and works fine. It will replace the "Y" once I fix this portion of the logic.

Comment: IMHO, your question isn't clear. If i understand correctly, there are date values in N16:N9000. You want to check **each of those dates** if they are `>=$C$6` and `>=$C$6` and `<=$C$8`. If yes, you want to put `Y` in another cell, if no, `N`. Or is it sufficient if **only one of the date values** matches that condition?

Comment: I need to test the dates in column N i.e. $N$16:$N$9000 to be >=$C$6 and <=$C$8    If true then "Y" which will be replaced with a SUMIF statement

Comment: So, you want to count how many date values are `>=$C$6` and `<=$C$8`?

Comment: I want to sum all values from another column where the dates mm/dd are between >=$C$6 and <=$C$8

Comment: Ok, i've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to count the values from another column according to date values `>=$C$6` and `<=$C$8`, you could adapt an example from the **[Conditional Counting and Summation HowTo](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Conditional_Counting_and_Summation#Tips_and_Tricks%3a_Items_Between_Two_Dates)**. It's based on the **[SUMPRODUCT function](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_SUMPRODUCT_function)**.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($N$16:$N$9000 >= $C$6; $N$16:$N$9000 <= $C$8; $P$16:$P$900)
```

(assuming that `P16:P9000` holds the values to sum up)